# How did the gets function ever make into the standard?

Tags: c, standardization

We all know the dangers of `gets`.

It is also on the way out in C11.

That makes me wonder: how did it ever get into the standard to begin with? Weren't the problems with it obvious at the time of standardization?

Comment: recommended reading: **[On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)**

Comment: Standardized... when? `getstring` with the same functionality existed in [B](https://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/b/manu/manu.html#Section7_1). And something similar existed in BCPL.

Comment: Things were a lot different in 1972.

Comment: The tendency has seemed to be to create a second method with a prefix in front, as to not break old code, for example wcprintf rather than just printf for a wide-character version.  So compatibility seems to hold more importance in C++ than forcing usage of more proper methods.

Comment: @gnat I'm sorry, but how is this supposed to be a discussion?

Comment: @Pablo, are you just expecting the play by play to be the answer? If there is any interpretation then that is where there would be discussion or do you think we'd all agree on why something was done many years ago?

Comment: @JBKing I don't see how something done many years ago couldn't have been documented. You seem to be under the impression that we already know the answers before asking the questions.

Comment: @Pablo, no I believe those asking questions have assumptions that may get tested by those of us giving comments and answers. For example, your idea that it would be documented and then perfectly preserved, never to be revised or pillaged is an assumption.

Comment: @JBKing Yet you have not provided any evidence that this is the case here. The question was put on hold before people could come and give their inputs. Are you aware that people directly involved in the creation and standardization of the `gets` function are probably still alive and well and could have given a solid, backup up by data answer? Or scholars, long-time programmers etc. Just because you don't have it doesn't mean it doesn't exist. When I don't know the answer (or whether there's one) to a question I skip it/comment on it. When it's people on Programmers, they vote to close? Funny..

Comment: @Pablo where was that required? You didn't see how this could become a discussion where given the back and forth we have had that is a discussion where I highly suggest you learn terminology as your reputation doesn't inspire confidence that you know how SE sites work.

Comment: @JBKing Don't mix things for your own beneft. We are not discussing the answer, we're discussing your judgement. Of course it has to be a discussion. But if you're getting as low as counting points, you can scrape the part where you try to reason altogether. If you would take a look at my interactions throughout the network instead of prejudge , you'd see if I'm really interested in spurring discussions. I know how this site works and that's why I firmly believe you are misjudging this question. This question deserves to be answered objectively, and you're in the middle of the way to that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32189/discussion-between-jb-king-and-pablo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gets` was invented at a time when there were no millions of malicious hackers trying to steal your financial data via the internet. There was no internet to speak of. People didn't put their entire personal lives on computers. Only highly paid specialists were ever supposed to have access to digital computers *at all*.

Briefly, the threat-countermeasure trade-off was totally different in 1972 - so different that what seems like an incredible oversight today was more like a hasty but ultimately inconsequential pragmatic choice of leaving out error checking.

Comment: Also, at that time, computer resources where scarce and costly. So perhaps passing an additional argument was not worth the trouble.